# How to get SSL on a service?

Tags: ssl, ubuntu-16.04

I'm building a website which uses a routing (as in street nav) service which I'm running on a seperate server on port 8002 (running ubuntu 16.04). ([Github link to the router project](https://github.com/valhalla/valhalla))

The website itself is hosted by one.com. The problem arises when I use SSL on the website.

Because my route server has no SSL certificate, I get an error when I try to retrieve the route. The routing server is just using a public IP adress.

The router uses [this](https://github.com/kevinkreiser/prime_server) webserver but I can't find any information on how to implement an SSL certificate on it.

My question is, what would be the best way to get this working properly while I keep hosting the routing service on my own server.

I was thinking of creating a script on the website server that handles the route retrieval instead of the browser(not sure yet if this approach would work).

Please excuse me if my lack of knowledge on this subject is all too apparent. I'm just getting started experimenting with this and I'm still learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy approach: Set up Apache or nginx as a reverse proxy in front of all this, give them a proper SSL cert (e.g. LetsEncrypt) and then get the data via plain HTTP from the backend and send it to the clients via HTTPS.